# Issue with jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a little problem when using `datepicker` widget. In my application I have a form for article editing with `datetime` field. When I choose to edit an article it creation date is populated in the format

> 2013-09-22

and when I choose new date from `datepicker` the date in the field become

> 20132013-09-25

How to fix this?

I'm calling `datepicker` by this way:

```
  $('creationDate'),datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [jQuery UI Datepicker documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/), the right format for 4 digit year format is

```
yy - year (four digit)
```

So changing this will fix your problem.

```
$('creationDate').datepicker({  // USE . instead of ,
     dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'     //This should fix your problem
    });
```

**FYI:** Not sure may be typo, `creationDate` is an ID or CLASS?  Make sure of the right selector.

Comment: @ВладиславНайденов Glad to help you.